# Custom image in ribbon created by macro in Project

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, ms-project

We have a macro in this file that on the FileOpen event (Project_Open in our case, but I'm trying to make it a little bit general) is creating a RibbonXML string and loads it as a CustomUI, like below:

```
Function CreateRibbon()
    Dim ribbonXml As String
    ribbonXml = "<customUI ....>
    ....
    ribbonXml = "<mso:button id="customButton" getImage=""GetImage"" ....>
    ....
    ActiveProject.SetCustomUI (ribbonXml)
End Function
```

Under this function, I specified the GetImage function

```
Public Function GetImage(Ctrl As IRibbonControl) As IPictureDisp // I tried 'As String' as well
    On Error Resume Next
    If Ctrl.ID = "SiemensLogo" Then
        GetImage = "FormRegionMenu"
    Else
        GetImage = "HappyFace"
    End If 'Ctrl.ID?  
End Function 'GetImage
```

When I open the project, it shows an error message:

```
Automation error. Exception occured.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please repost your CreateRibbon function in valid syntax and I'll have a look.